Missing TWordApplication in Embarcadero 12.2 Athens
Former versions of Embarcadero C++Builder had Office controls TWordApplication, TWordDocument, etc. Does anyone know where I can find them in C++Builder 12.2 Athens?
I looked into the list of registered Type Libraries, but could not find a promising library name.

The old Office components have not been installed by default for a very long time, but they are still available for manual install.  In the $(BDS)\bin folder are several packages which you can install via the IDE's Component | Install Packages dialog, depending on which version of Office you need to interact with:

dclofficexp290.bpl
dcloffice2K290.bpl
dcloffice2010290.bpl

